# Existence of a Vampire number on the form $v = xy = a^bb^a$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

> A number $v = xy$  with an even number $n$ of digits formed by multiplying
>   a pair of $n/2$-digit numbers (where the digits are taken from the original
>   number in any order) $x$ and $y$ together. Pairs of trailing zeros are not
>   allowed. If $v$ is a vampire number, then $x$ and $y$ are called its "fangs."

Quoted from http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VampireNumber.html

Example: $60  \cdot  21 = 1260$

Does there exist a non-trivial vampire number $v $ such that

$v = xy = a^bb^a$ with integers $ a,b > 1 $ ?

Is there a way to show that this $v$ exists without having to check every known vampire number with an algorithm?

Comment: There are some words or symbols missing from your mathworld quote. Can you edit them in, please?

Comment: Sorry about that! Cameron Buie was faster than me fixing it though.

Comment: For what it's worth, the first 87 vampire numbers are listed at http://oeis.org/A014575/b014575.txt